# Two Values in Dropdown

Tags: ms-access

Access 2007. Is there a way to display two values in a combobox.  I realize the combobox is bound to a field in a table, and it can only be bound to one field, but when you click the combobox I have it showing two field, then when you choose and release we would like to display both values.  Is there anyway to do that.  We don't want to add another text box just to show this additional field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you can do without an additional textbox is set up your recordset to include two fields in the one:

```
 SELECT ID, Surname & ", " & Forename FROM Customers
```

ID is the bound field, so it does not much matter how many fields are concatenated in the display.